# Find Jaccard similarity between 2 vectors of different lengths in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two tensors (1D array of integers) of unequal lengths and I want to calculate the jaccard similarity between them in PyTorch.

This is how the pure python code looks like

```
def js(list1, list2):
    intersection = len(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))
    union = (len(set(list1)) + len(set(list2))) - intersection
    return float(intersection) / union
```

And this is how the pytorch version looks like (valid for same-length arrays only)

```
def js_pt(list1, list2):
    intersection = (list1 * list2).abs().sum(dim=-1)
    sum_ = torch.sum(list1.abs() + list2.abs(), dim=-1)
    jac = (intersection) / (sum_ - intersection)
    return (1 - jac)
```

I wanted to calculate the jaccard similarity between tensors that are of unequal lengths

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to calculate the similarity by the following approach.

```
la1 = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5])
la2 = torch.tensor([4,5,6,7])

def js(l1, la2):
    combined = torch.cat((la1, la2))
    union, counts = combined.unique(return_counts=True)
    intersection = union[counts > 1]
    return torch.numel(intersection) / torch.numel(union)

js(la1, la2)
>>> 0.2857142857142857
```

This works for unequal-sized tensors as well